# showlabels/showkeys overlap with main tex

Tags: numbering, showlabels

I am writing a long article with many long, displayed equations plus references to these equations and theorems.  If I use `showlabels`, sometimes the labels will overlap with the displayed equations.  That does not happen with `showkeys`, but the label for in-text citation appears on top of the citations.

Question:  Is it possible to tweak `showlabels` so that labels for displayed equations appear on margin?  Alternatively, can we tweak `showkeys` so that labels for in-text citations appear on the margin?

I already tried `\usepackage[marginal]{showlabels}` but to no avail, and `\usepackage[left]{showlabels}` simply remove the labels for displayed equations.  I have no idea how to tweak `showkeys`.

I suspect that this question has been asked before but I was not able to google an answer.  Thanks for your help.

---

Minimal working example (by `jmc`):

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{showlabels}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \label{ftc}
 \int_a^b f'(x) \,\mathrm dx = f(b) - f(a)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If I change `amsart` to the `article` class, the problem is gone. It is likely something with equation numbers being printed on the left vs right.

Comment: The equation labels should indeed appear in the margin (the `[marginal]` option is the default).  Do you have an [example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) of this misbehaviour?

Comment: @NormanGray It think the problem occurs when one has equation numbers on the left (e.g. with the `amsart` class).